# How to get the amount of working hours between 2 dates - Assigned to each day

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

**Update:**

Initially the problem was that the solution I had were too slow. However, I have been working in the same file as I did when I started in PowerBI. I am now redoing the whole file to make it more efficient and try to adhere/implement best practices.

The problem now is not that it is slow, but I need some help with editing the code so I get the needed result (see tables below).

**Context:**

I want to find out how many hours workers on our ships have been on board.
This will be used as the denominator for a couple of KPIs in an HSE setting.

**My intention:**

I want to be able to find out how many hours have been worked on each specific day.
This should be possible to display in a line chart where the days are on the X-axis, and amount of hours on the Y-axis. I also want to be able to show how many hours worked on a specific day, month etc.

**Short sample of the dataset:**

| ID | Start Date | Start Time | End Date | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 873246786 | 20.03.2023 | 12:00 | 15.04.2023 | 13:00 |
| 345984358 | 30.04.2023 | 16:00 | 16.05.2023 | 09:00 |

**Expected/needed result:**

| ID | Date | Hours on board |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 873246786 | 20.03.2023 | 12 |
| 873246786 | 21.03.2023 | 24 |
| 873246786 | ... | 24 |
| 873246786 | 14.04.2023 | 24 |
| 873246786 | 15.04.2023 | 13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 345984358 | 30.04.2023 | 8 |
| 345984358 | 01.05.2023 | 24 |
| 345984358 | ... | 24 |
| 345984358 | 15.05.2023 | 24 |
| 345984358 | 16.05.2023 | 9 |

**Actual result:**

| ID | Date | Hours on board |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 873246786 | 31.03.2023 | 12 |
| 873246786 | 31.03.2023 | 24 |
| 873246786 | ... | 24 |
| 873246786 | 30.04.2023 | 24 |
| 873246786 | 30.04.2023 | 13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 345984358 | 30.04.2023 | 8 |
| 345984358 | 31.05.2023 | 24 |
| 345984358 | ... | 24 |
| 345984358 | 31.05.2023 | 24 |
| 345984358 | 31.05.2023 | 9 |

I have found a solution, which works fine for assigning workhours to the correct month (see actual result above). However, I would like to get a table as described/shown in the table displaying expected/needed result. I used the solution as described [here](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/power-bi-between-dates-working-hours-solution/)

What modifications could be done to achieve the needed result?

Here is the code I have now:

```
let
    Kilde = Sql.Database("XXXXX", "YYYYYY"),
        CREW_CrewActivity = Kilde{[Schema="CREW",Item="CrewActivity"]}[Data],
    #"Fjernede kolonner" = Table.RemoveColumns(CREW_CrewActivity,{"LastModified", "X_CREATED", "X_CREATED_BY", "X_DEFAULT_TZ", "CompanyId", "LocationCompany", "LocationFlagState", "LocationImo", "LocationMainType", "LocationManager", "LocationMmsi", "LocationName", "LocationOwner", "LocationSegment", "LocationTypes", "Bunk", "Cabin", "Company", "CompanyName", "GangwayLog", "SignOffPlace", "SignOnPlace", "TagId", "FirstName", "LastName", "MiddleName", "Position", "Vessel"}),
    #"Filtrerte rader" = Table.SelectRows(#"Fjernede kolonner", each ([SignOff] <> null)),

    // For SignOff
    #"Erstattet verdi SignOff" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Filtrerte rader", "T", " ", Replacer.ReplaceText, {"SignOff"}),
    #"Uttrekte første tegn SignOff" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Erstattet verdi SignOff", {{"SignOff", each Text.Start(_, 16), type text}}),

    // For SignOn (added steps for SignOn)
    #"Erstattet verdi SignOn" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uttrekte første tegn SignOff", "T", " ", Replacer.ReplaceText, {"SignOn"}),
    #"Uttrekte første tegn SignOn" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Erstattet verdi SignOn", {{"SignOn", each Text.Start(_, 16), type text}}),
    
    #"Del kolonne med skilletegn" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Uttrekte første tegn SignOn", "SignOn", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"SignOn.1", "SignOn.2"}),
    #"Del kolonne med skilletegn1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Del kolonne med skilletegn", "SignOff", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"SignOff.1", "SignOff.2"}),
    #"Endret type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Del kolonne med skilletegn1",{{"SignOn.1", type date}, {"SignOn.2", type text}, {"SignOff.1", type date}, {"SignOff.2", type text}}),
    #"Erstattet verdi" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Endret type",":","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"SignOn.2", "SignOff.2"}),
    #"Kolonner med nye navn" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Erstattet verdi",{{"SignOn.1", "Start Date"}, {"SignOn.2", "Start Time"}, {"SignOff.1", "Stop Date"}, {"SignOff.2", "Stop Time"}}),
    #"Egendefinert lagt til" = Table.AddColumn(#"Kolonner med nye navn", "Egendefinert", each 
        [
            SD = [Start Date],
            ST = Number.Round(Number.From([Start Time])/100,0),
            ED = [Stop Date],
            ET = Number.Round(Number.From([Stop Time])/100,0),
            LD = List.Dates( SD, Number.From ( ED-SD ) +1, Duration.From(1)),
            LT = if SD = ED then { ET - ST } else { 24-ST } & List.Repeat( { 24 }, List.Count( LD )-2 ) & { ET },
            t = Table.FromColumns(
                {
                    List.Transform ( LD, Date.EndOfMonth ),
                    LT
                },  type table [ Date = Date.Type, Hrs = Int8.Type ]
            )
        ][t]
    )[[Id],[CrewUNID],[Egendefinert]],
    #"Fjernede feil" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Egendefinert lagt til", {"Egendefinert"}),
    #"Utvidet Egendefinert" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Fjernede feil", "Egendefinert", {"Date", "Hrs"}, {"Date", "Hrs"})
in
    #"Utvidet Egendefinert"
```

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with your expected results.

Comment: Yes. After I added it the custom column PowerBI is stuck in loading forever. 
PowerBI is stuck in loading while it is "Creating relationships in model".

To address this I tried to turn off the settings that automatically creates relationships, identify data types and turned off the smart/auto date stuff.
However it did not help. (And I do not use DirectQuery)

Comment: When I'm working on a large dataset, I use a parameter to limit the amount of data that is loaded while I'm designing/building the model. Then what I have found, it is best to save and close PBI Desktop, then re-open the pbix, change the parameter to load everything, and usually it refreshes more smoothly/quickly. Example `FilterMaxRows = if MaxRows <=0 then Source else Table.LastN(Source, MaxRows)`. Additionally, you can publish the dataset with limited rows, then change the parameter in PBI Service.

Comment: That workaround/solution seems interesting. Could you show me how you would implement it in this code?

Comment: Hi, please see updates above. The question is now about changing the result, and not about efficiency. I am redoing my whole file from scratch.

Comment: I will test as soon as I can and follow up.

Comment: It worked excellently. I will test and do a manual control to see that everything is correct otherwise. Sorry for the late reply, had some issues with the SQL server that needed resolving. Thank you so much horseyride!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what you have, but it accounts for a few more things

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}, {"Start Time", type time}, {"End Time", type time}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Dates", each List.Transform({Number.From([Start Date])..Number.From([End Date])}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Times", each  
    let a =  if [End Date]=[Start Date] then {Duration.Hours([End Time] - [Start Time])} else {Duration.Hours(#time(24,0,0)-[Start Time])},
    b = if List.Count( [Dates] )>1 then  List.Repeat( { 24 }, List.Count( [Dates] )-2 )  else {},
    c = if List.Count( [Dates] )>1 then {Duration.Hours([End Time]-#time(0,0,0))} else {}
    in a&b&c
),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "ID2", each List.Repeat( { [ID] }, List.Count( [Dates] ) )),
Combine = Table.FromColumns(
    {List.Combine(#"Added Custom2"[ID2])} &
    {List.Combine(#"Added Custom2"[Dates])} &
    {List.Combine(#"Added Custom2"[Times])}
    ,{"ID","Date","Hours on board"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Combine,{{"Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Feel free to swap to Duration.Minutes if you want